# Module to draw over other apps in flutter?

Tags: flutter, system-alert-window

I am trying to make a alarm app where  I want to display a popup and play a sound so that the user gets alarmed. I first found the System_Alert_Window module, but it looks like it lacks a bit of styling property. I can set the background color of the whole popup + I cant attach any image. So, is there any alternative to that module to draw over other apps?

Comment: Try flutter_platform_alert: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_alert

Comment: I tried using it but it doesnt look so promising? Can you add an answer showing how to use it the right way?

Comment: I haven't used the package before, so I'm unable to extend that help. But the example file in the package should answer most of your questions, or the GitHub repository link.

Comment: Ig so. Well anyway I would look into the code :)